# How can i make a Gridview or Listview

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

How can i make a jQuery Mobile Gridview that can pop-up with values from a database once a button is clicked?

Comment: Well for start it's nice to know if you work on a platform like Magento, Wordpress, Joomla etc. Else you could just add a class from jQuery and style it in two different ways. That's how I see things from what you said :)

Comment: you need to use the jquery grid or a custom grid ?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 divs, 1 for the popup window (Kendo Window) and 1 inside that div for the grid.

Here is how you can make the **window**:

```
var header = "CIR Details";

 $("#popupDiv").kendoWindow(
 {
    title:header,
    width:"600px",
    visible:true,
    resizable:false,
    modal:true
 });
 dataManagementWindow = $("#popupDiv").data("kendoWindow");
kendoWindow.center();
```

and the **grid**:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid(
{
dataSource: 
{
    data: columnDefs,
    pageSize: 10
},
columns: columnDefs,
scrollable: false,
pageable: true
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

And here is an example for the **dataSource** for the grid:

```
columnDefs({ field: "Title 1", template: "value 1" },
           { field: "Title 2", template: "value 2" },
           { field: "Title 3", template: "value 3" });
```